# Problem when select'ing by ROWID inside procedure

Tags: database, oracle, rowid

I've spent hours trying to find a fix to this problem, but since I'm unable to find I've decided to ask here.

I'm doing a procedure to retrieve information from a table based on the row's `ROWID` and with the results I'm doing some custom query using `execute immediate`. I've reduced the problem to the following lines, which I'm executing directly in SQL Developer:

```
declare
  row_id   ROWID;
  consulta VARCHAR2(1000);
begin  
  row_id := 'AAAEC5AAFAAAADHAAC';
  select 'insert into ' || 
    (select TABLA       from BITACORA where rowid = row_id) || ' values(' || 
    (select VALOR_VIEJO from BITACORA where rowid = row_id) || ')' 
    into Consulta from dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Consulta);
    --execute immediate Consulta;        
end;
```

The previous lines doesn't work as it is. When I print the contents of `Consulta` it shows:

```
insert into  values()
```

but if I eliminate the variable `row_id` and put it directly in the queries like this, it works:

```
declare
  consulta VARCHAR2(1000);
begin  
  select 'insert into ' || 
    (select TABLA       from BITACORA where rowid = 'AAAEC5AAFAAAADHAAC') || ' values(' || 
    (select VALOR_VIEJO from BITACORA where rowid = 'AAAEC5AAFAAAADHAAC') || ')' 
    into Consulta from dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Consulta);
    --execute immediate Consulta;        
end;
```

Displaying what I would expect, something like:

```
insert into MI_TABLA values(1,'Hola','Adios',3,1)
```

This is not work-related, so there is no concerns about performance/security. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Can you try putting rowid = :row_id?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried and it gives me an error :(, think it is because : is used only for out variables

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use the CHARTOROWID() conversion function:

```
row_id := CHARTOROWID('AAAEC5AAFAAAADHAAC');
```

According to the [oracle doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#i27947), this would not be necessary for the data type urowid.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get an explain plan of this:

```
select TABLA       from BITACORA where rowid = 'AAAEC5AAFAAAADHAAC';
```

and this:

```
select TABLA       from BITACORA where rowid = :1;
```

It depends on which version of Oracle you are on, but try this:

```
explain plan for
select TABLA       from BITACORA where rowid = 'AAAEC5AAFAAAADHAAC';

select plan_table_output from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'serial'));

delete from plan table;
```

And then this:

```
explain plan for
select TABLA       from BITACORA where rowid = :1;

select plan_table_output from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'serial'));

delete from plan table;
```

Update your question with the output and that might give some further clues.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you selecting from DUAL?  Unless you've omitted something vital in your simplification this ought to work for you:

```
declare
  row_id   ROWID;
  consulta VARCHAR2(1000);
begin  
  row_id := 'AAAEC5AAFAAAADHAAC';
  select 'insert into ' ||TABLA || ' values(' ||VALOR_VIEJO|| ')' 
  into   Consulta
  where rowid = row_id; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Consulta);
  execute immediate Consulta;        
end;
/
```